# Binding does not work for Grid.ColumnDefinitions inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I have a DataTemplate that contains ItemsControl, which in its turn uses a grid as ItemsPanel. I would like to bind columns width of this grid but it simply does not work: the width of all columns that I try to bind turns out to be just 1* (that is a default I suppose). However, I can see that these values change in the code, so the problem is in the binding. Any ideas?

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MySource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:MetroWindow}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding LeftColumnWidth}" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding CenterColumnWidth}" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RightColumnWidth}" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: `ItemsPanel` affects the **container** for your items. Not each individual item. Imagine if your items had different column widths, which width would the container choose? Look into `ItemTemplates` instead.

Comment: Putting Grid definition to DataTemplate does not help either, but now I even cannot see my Grid.

Comment: Take a look at [snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), this enables you to see the datacontext, etc during runtime. This will show you what the DataContext and binding values are on the component you are snooping, and help you fix your binding errors, if any.

Comment: Also if your values change in the code, and is not reflecting on the UI, its because the Binding Mode should be TwoWay, and the UpdateSourceTrigger should be PropertyChanged. Is your PropertyChanged Event firing in your code behind? If it is null, it means your DataContext is not set/set incorrectly. There can be a few issues causing this to happen.

Comment: Two simple ways to begin debugging this. Put a breakpoint in the getter of `LeftColumnWidth`, is the view trying to get it? Also, keep an eye on your Output window in Visual Studio while debugging. It might alert you that the binding you've defined is not valid.